# Custom view decorations in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VS Code extension and it uses a `TreeDataProvider` to create a list of items. The list has nested children and I would like to show a count for these in the parent.

I've looked for examples and tried to understand how the git extension does it but no luck. Perhaps someone can provide an example of how to do this.

[image: Count example in GIT extension]

[image: Count example in file explorer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of VS code version 1.52, the [`FileDecorationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileDecorationProvider) is available to use, which is a way to add a text badge to a **TreeItem**. Related [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54938) for more context.

If you are using `TreeItem` then you will need to specify a `resourceUri` property which you then use to identify where to apply the badge.

To be clear the badge is limited to text and does not include the option to put it in a circle badge, like in the first picture of the question.

Here is a simple code snippet on how to use it:

```
    class CountDecorationProvider {
      constructor() {
        this.disposables = [];
        this.disposables.push(vscode.window.registerFileDecorationProvider(this));
    } 

    provideFileDecoration(uri) {
      const showCountFor = "/aUserHere";
      if (uri.path === showCountFor) {
        return {
          badge: "10",
          tooltip: "User count"
        };
      }
    }

    dispose() {
      this.disposables.forEach((d) => d.dispose());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for custom decorations in views appears to be a work-in-progress. There has been an API for it in the ["proposed state"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api) for a while, see:

- [Make decoration provider API public (#54938)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54938)
- [relevant section in `vscode.proposed.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/842b2ede43066445a0721d410cad004499731cd5/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts#L526-L553)

Source Control and Problem decorations [already shown](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_custom-view-file-resource-decorations) in custom views if `TreeView.resourceUri` is set.

- Source Control decorations are managed via the [Source Control API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider) - each `SourceControlResourceState` instance can have `decorations` attached to it. That would be how the Git extension you mentioned does it.
- Problem decorations are derived from the "problems" (errors, warnings...) associated with a URI. These are also shown in the Problems panel. Problems can be created using the [Diagnostics API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#provide-diagnostics) or with a [problem matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the Decoration Provider is what I want. Hopefully, it will be available soon.

Comment: Looks like there was some confusion over the decorator to be used for badge count and this is the relevant issue to follow:
[Badges in custom views and containers ](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38426)