# VSCode Modify File Explorer Appearance Through Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm wondering if it is possible to gain access to the file explorer tree to change what a file looks like visually. This would be similar to the way a new file would turn green and have a "U" next to it if the project is source controlled, or a file would appear red if errors were detected in it. In my case I would like to change the color (or anything visual for that matter) of the filename depending on the contents of one of the files in the project. So when that file changes, different filenames in the file explorer would get highlighted.

In looking through the vscode APIs every method or property related to a tree appears to be for custom trees only. In this case I would like to have something like `vscode.window.getTreeDataProvider(viewId);` such that I could call `fileTreeDataProvider.getTreeItem()` and modify the appearance of the tree item.

Is anything like this possible currently?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504718/vs-code-extensions-make-a-count-badge/54505288#54505288

Comment: Thanks @Gama11 I missed that post. The Decoration Provider is what I need, hopefully it is made available for the default File Tree and not just custom Trees. Following this issue now https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54938.

Comment: I think deocrations are tired to URIs rather than specific views, so it would work for both.